# Logistical Regression of Data with Categorical Variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I am trying to create a logistical regression of data for the following dataset.

This is what my data looks like

```
glimpse(Squirrels.Count)
```

And this appears

```
Rows: 6 Columns: 3 $ primary_fur_color \<chr\> "Black", "Black", "Cinnamon", "Cinnamon", "Gray", "Gray" $ runs_from         \<int\> 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 $ n                 \<int\> 70, 30, 290, 85, 1825, 524
```

Where n is the number of counts from the 0s to the 1s.

Tried the following code:

```
Squirrels.Count %>% 
  ggplot(data = Squirrels.Count, aes(x = runs_from, y = runs_from)) +   
  geom_point( aes(color = primary_fur_color)) +   
  stat_smooth(method="glm", se=TRUE, method.args = list(family=binomial), aes(group = primary_fur_color))
```

But it results in an error.

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(Squirrels.count)` as part of your question. Also, what is your intent - to create a chart or to create a model? Your question suggests the latter, but your code points to the former.

Comment: This isn't enough information to reproduce the problem. However, I've spotted that you're both piping in the `Squirrels.Count` data, *and* declaring the `data` variable. Does the problem persist if you only use 1 of the two?